# Re-rendering Rails partial AFTER saving the model through a form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm re-rendering a partial after submitting a `remote: true` form, but my problem is that it seems to re-render the partial BEFORE fully completing the form's update action. As a result, it renders old data on the page, and shows updated info only after a full refresh (or when I submit the form yet again). Is there a way to force the application to re-render the partial after everything is completed, in order to display only the new info? Or am I missing a step here?

> update.js.erb:

```
$("#methods").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'methods') %>");
```

> owner_controller.rb

```
respond_to :html, :js, :json

def update
  if owner.update_attributes(owner_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  else
    fail_update
  end
end
```

Comment: Use the 'locals' option in render to pass the variables to the view.  Such as render partial: "form", locals: {user: @user}...More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#methods").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'methods', locals: {owner: @owner}) %>");
```

and assuming you are setting owner in a before action, change the variable you set from owner to @owner.

Answer (score 0):

in update.js.erb

```
$("#methods").html("<%= j(render partial: 'methods') %>");
<% unless @owner.errors.present? %> 
 $('#some_form')[0].reset()
<% end %>
```